# Get back first non-null value grouped by some other columns

Tags: sql

How to go from left to right?
Basically for each TIME-person combo, I need the first non-null value from the id columns.
[image]

Comment: select t.time,t.person,max(id1)as m_id1, max(id2)as m_id2,max(id3) as m_id3, max(id4)as m_id4 from your_table as t group by t.time,t.person    Could you please try this

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate by `time` and `person` and take the max of the other 4 columns:

```sql
SELECT
    time,
    person,
    MAX(id1) AS id1,
    MAX(id2) AS id2,
    MAX(id3) AS id3,
    MAX(id4) AS id4
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    time,
    person;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way that I know of (i.e. in my experience of practical situations where this comes up) is to use PIVOT and UNPIVOT (may not be necessary in the example above, but if you have multiple rows with id1's for a time/person combo it provides a nice mechanism to do this).

Unfortunately how to do this depends on which SQL DBMS you're using. Below example will work for MS SQL Server. Oracle has similar functionality. MySQL/PostgreSQL I don't know that well, but I don't think they have PIVOT/UNPIVOT though you may find something similar if you search for "lateral derived table" or "cross join lateral":

```
SELECT [Time], Person, id1, id2, id3, id4
FROM    (SELECT [Time], Person, id, idval
            FROM (SELECT [Time], Person, id1, id2, id3, id4 FROM #test) pvt
            UNPIVOT (idval FOR id IN (id1, id2, id3, id4)) AS unpvt
        ) AS unpivoted
PIVOT (
        MIN(idval) FOR [id] IN ([id1], [id2], [id3], [id4])
    ) AS pivoted
```

For this example, I assumed that by the "first" non-null value you meant the one with the lowest ID, i.e. MIN(idval), but this may not be what you're after. There are ways to use other columns to determine which is first, e.g. if time should determine what "first" means then something like this could work:

```
SELECT [Time], Person, id1%1000000 'id1', id2%1000000 'id2', id3%1000000 'id3', id4%1000000 'id4'
FROM    (SELECT [Time], Person, id, idval+(1000000*[Time]) 'idval'
            FROM (SELECT [Time], Person, id1, id2, id3, id4 FROM #test) pvt
            UNPIVOT (idval FOR id IN (id1, id2, id3, id4)) AS unpvt
        ) AS unpivoted
PIVOT (
        MIN(idval) FOR [id] IN ([id1], [id2], [id3], [id4])
    ) AS pivoted
```

Last resort, you can also to something like this (ugly as hell IMHO and not great for performance either):

```
SELECT tp.Person, tp.[Time], t_id1.id 'id1', t_id2.id 'id', t_id3.id 'id3', t_id4.id 'id4'
    FROM (SELECT [Time], Person FROM #Test t GROUP BY [Time], Person) tP
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Time], Person, MIN(id1) 'id' FROM #Test t WHERE t.id1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY [Time],Person) t_id1 ON t_id1.Person = tP.Person
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Time], Person, MIN(id2) 'id' FROM #Test t WHERE t.id2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY [Time],Person) t_id2 ON t_id2.Person = tP.Person
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Time], Person, MIN(id3) 'id' FROM #Test t WHERE t.id3 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY [Time],Person) t_id3 ON t_id3.Person = tP.Person
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Time], Person, MIN(id4) 'id' FROM #Test t WHERE t.id4 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY [Time],Person) t_id4 ON t_id3.Person = tP.Person
```