# Fill out missing dates based on the minimum date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with dates (the dates will always be ordered) and a value for example:

```
       Dates           Value
     2007-01-01         10
     2007-01-02         Null
     2007-01-03         Null
     2007-01-04         Null
     2007-01-05         20
     2007-01-06         Null
     2007-01-07         40
```

I want to replace the 'Null' values with the value from the earliest date that contains a value, for example:

```
     Dates             Value
     2007-01-01         10
     2007-01-02         10
     2007-01-03         10
     2007-01-04         10
     2007-01-05         20
     2007-01-06         20
     2007-01-07         40
```

Comment: Where does the first value, `10`, come from? This, however, is known as a "gaps and island" problem; if you search this terminology you will very likely find your solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the last non null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61746094/get-the-last-non-null-value)

Comment: _(the dates will always be ordered)_ No they will not. Rows in a table have no defined order. Rows in a resultset have no defined order if the query that generates it has no ORDER BY clause. Do not assume otherwise based what you think you see when a database that has limited data and low contention.

Comment: I guess the first line of the correct data:
 Dates            Value
 2007-01-01    10
So @Larnu is right, it's a gaps and islands problem

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68042693/61305) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70271225/61305).

Answer (score 0):

As an answer :

```
CREATE TABLE A_TABLE
(A_DATE     DATE,
 A_VALUE    INT);

INSERT INTO A_TABLE VALUES
(' 2007-01-01', 10),
(' 2007-01-02', Null),
(' 2007-01-03', Null),
(' 2007-01-04', Null),
(' 2007-01-05', 20),
(' 2007-01-06', Null),
(' 2007-01-07', 40)

WITH 
T1 AS
(
SELECT *, COALESCE(LEAD(A_DATE) OVER(ORDER BY A_DATE), '9999-12-31') AS END_DATE
FROM   A_TABLE
WHERE  A_VALUE IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT T.A_DATE, T1.A_VALUE
FROM   A_TABLE AS T
       JOIN T1 ON T.A_DATE >= T1.A_DATE AND T.A_DATE < T1.END_DATE;
```